# Custom post type search only title WP_query and title capital and small letter issue

Tags: php, wordpress

Post title: "Test"

When searching for "test" then autosuggestion is not showing result but when searching for first word with capital letter, "Test", then autosuggestion is showing.

```php
$results = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => array( 'dream'),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 221,
    's'              => stripslashes($_POST['search']),
));

$items = array();
while ( $results->have_posts() ) {
    $results->the_post();
    $items[] = get_the_title();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"autosuggestion is showing"_? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be ways to make your database case insensitive; this may work for you, but I wouldn't trust that.

Instead, I'd adjust the search query to include both capitalized and lowercased search terms (untested):

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', static function ( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->is_search ) {
        return;
    }

    $s = $query->get( 's', '' );

    $query->set( 's', ucwords( $s ) . ' ' . strtolower( $s ) );
} );
```